# Weblogic 12.2.1.0.0 remove session from request during redirect with JSF

Tags: session, jsf-2, weblogic, weblogic12c

req.getSession(false) had value just before redirection but is returning null after redirection from Weblogic 12.2.1.0.0. ServletResponseImpl.sendRedirect is removing session instance and sessionDestroyed method is not getting called.

This works fine in tomcat and older version of weblogic.

Please find below stack trace:
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendRedirect(ServletResponseImpl.java:1027)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendRedirect(ServletResponseImpl.java:948)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:176)

Comment: **This is a bug in Weblogic. Contact weblogic team for fix.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue with the code.

This is a bug in Weblogic. Contact Weblogic team for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is to enable session sharing refer - https://technology.amis.nl/2012/01/18/sharing-session-state-between-jee-web-application-through-weblogic-session-descriptor-of-sharing-enabled/